# Creating a sin formula in C

Tags: c, function, trigonometry

The program compiles but when running it I am not getting the correct values back from my inputs. I have looked for a way to make the sine formula and have found this one but I don't believe it was right.

Is my formula correct? I think just running the `sin` function in C is giving me the wrong value as well.

**Update:** I'm still getting the wrong values with these changes if I input 1.5 and 4. I'm getting 0.000 and a random integer

```
 /*
  * Function mySin is using a sin formula to get the sin of x
  * the function then returns the sin value computed 
  * Parameters -for function mySin are "x" is the value for sin
  *            -"n"is the number of series to run
  *
  *The program also uses the sin(x) function to get the real sin
  * 
  */ 

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

 int mySin(double x, int n){

    int i=0;
    double sinx=0;

    for(i=1; i<=n; i+=2){
        sinx=(pow(x,i)+sinx); // 
    }

    return sinx;
    }


    int main(double sinx){

    double realSin=0;

    double x=0;
    int n=0;

    printf("Please input x and n:");
    scanf("%lf",&x);
    scanf("%d",&n);

    mySin(x,n);

    realSin=sin(x);

    printf("mySin= %f\n sin=%d\n",sinx,realSin); 
 }
```

Comment: Your formula is wrong in at least three ways.

Answer (score 6):

Your `mySin` function is wrong in at least 5 separate ways. Using `**` to represent exponentiation (to avoid confusion with xor), the correct formula is

```
sin(x) = x - x**3/3! + x**5/5! - x**7/7! + x**9/9! ...
```

Your implementation fails because

1. It discards the previous terms on every iteration of the loop.
2. It doesn't alternate signs.
3. It includes even-exponent terms.
4. It doesn't compute a factorial in the divisor.
5. The return type is int, discarding the fractional component of the computed result.

Furthermore, `main` is wrong in several more ways. The return value of `mySin` is completely ignored. Instead, `sinx` is the first argument to `main`, which is the number of command-line arguments the program received (including the name it was run as). Also, `%d` is used for all numbers in format strings, regardless of type, when it's only meant for `int`.

To fix `mySin`, have `i` only go over odd values, and have every iteration of the loop compute `x**i/i!` and add it into the current value of `sinx`.

To fix `main`, declare a local `sinx` variable in `main` and assign `sinx = mySin(x, n)` instead of declaring `sinx` as an argument. Also, use `%lf` for reading doubles with `scanf` and `%f` for writing doubles with `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

`mySin` should return `double`. You are returning `int`.

`sin` values can be calculated with the Fourier series.

Answer (score 1):

x is double so you have to use the **%lf** in scanf and **%f** in the printf

```
    double x;
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf ("%f", x);
```

Answer (score 1):

One more incorrect point in your code is that you're calculating power by `**`

There's no power operator in C. The compiler is treating `x**i` as `x * (*i)`. But since `i` is not a pointer, it returns the error you saw. You must use `pow()` instead